# CSS: How to add borders of different colors to input radio buttons labels?

Tags: html, css

I have some radio buttons grouped in a form (they have the same "name" property) and I want to add boxes/borders of different colors around them.Something like this:

Example:

[image: Example]

The code for CSS buttons:

```
.form ul {
list-style: none;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
}
ul li {
color: #4169E1;
display: block;
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;

}
ul li input[type=radio] {
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
}
ul li label {
display: block;
position: relative;
float: left;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 1.35em;
padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
margin: 1px auto;
height: 30px;
z-index: 9;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
}
ul li:hover label {
color: #6495ED;
}
ul li .check {
display: block;
position: absolute;
border: 5px solid #4169E1;
border-radius: 100%;
height: 21px;
width: 21px;
top: 30px;
/*left: 40px;*/
z-index: 5;
transition: border .25s linear;
-webkit-transition: border .25s linear;
}
ul li:hover .check {
border: 5px solid #6495ED;
}
ul li .check::before {
display: block;
position: absolute;
content: '';
border-radius: 100%;
height: 9px;
width: 9px;
top: 1px;
right: 1px;
left: 1.05px;
bottom: 1.05px;
margin: auto;
transition: background 0.25s linear;
-webkit-transition: background 0.25s linear;
}
input[type=radio]:checked~ .check {
border: 5px solid #0000FF;
}
input[type=radio]:checked~ .check::before {
background: #0000FF;
}
input[type=radio]:checked~ label {
color: #0000FF;
}
```

The HTML code:

```
<form>
                <ul id="radioButtons">
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="editor_opt1" name="selector" value="Opt1" ></input>
                        <label for="editor_opt1">Option 1</label>
                        <div class="check" ></div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="editor_opt2" name="selector" value="Opt2" ></input>
                        <label for="editor_opt2">Option 2</label>
                        <div class="check" ></div>
                    </li>
</ul>
</form>
```

The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/steLy9qe/
(which for whatever reason is badly displaced and doesn't look like in my actual page)

Comment: check your code as you have some unclosed tags <div class="check" </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your input inside your label, then apply styling to the label.

```css
li label {        
    border: 3px solid red;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}
li:nth-child(2) label {
    border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <ul id="radioButtons">
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" id="editor_opt1" name="selector" value="Opt1">
                Option 1
            </label>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" id="editor_opt2" name="selector" value="Opt2">
                Option 2
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great. I found it works even if I don't wrap the input inside the label. Would it be possible to give a custom width-size to the border? Because sometimes my options name don't have the same word length and I don't want the border-size to be relative to that.

Comment: Yes, you can give the label a default size and let it's contents occupy whatever width it needs. You can specify the size in any unit (px, em, etc) so long as it's displayed as block or inline-block. I've updated my answer with an example. If you change the property from `width` to `min-width`, you'll also allow the label to grow more, should it's contents exceed the available space.

Answer (score 0):

`:nth-of-type()` [should be of service.](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

```css
li:nth-of-type(odd) label {
  border: 2px solid #F00;
}
li:nth-of-type(even) label {
  border: 2px solid #0F0;
}
```

This styles the label of every odd and even list item in succession differently.

In your case

Answer (score 0):

You can use css nth-child property to access the li

```
    ul li:nth-child(1){
      border:1px solid red;
    }
    ul li:nth-child(2){
      border:1px solid blue;
    }
     ul li:first-child{
      border:1px solid red;
    }
 ul li:last--child{
      border:1px solid red;
    }
```